# Advantages of Linux Containers over Docker

Tags: docker, containers, linux

I'd like to understand the differences between Linux Containers and Docker, especially what kind of advantages Containers have in comparison to Docker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about devops, but rather about Linux programs. This would be better suited on Server Fault I think.

Comment: @tayworm Just because a question fits well on another site it doesn't mean it's off-topic on DevOps. After all one of the reasons for DevOps is to be a one-stop shop for all DevOps-related Q&As, see http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/22356/isnt-duplicate-of-server-fault. As both are DevOps-related commonly-used technologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker is a specific implementation of Linux containers, or if you want to be more precise Docker is a distribution of tools that includes `runc` which is an implementation of Linux containers. Other implementations include rkt, LXC, LXD, and (I think) Snappy from Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, docker is a little more now in Win2016 with Microsoft support: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon

Comment: Yes, which is why I put the more specific/pedantic version in there already ;)

Comment: Indeed. Just though it worth a mention docker is not linux centric anymore ;)